# Can I link numpy with AMD's gpu accelerated blas library

Tags: python, numpy, opencl, gpgpu

I reconized numpy can link with blas, and I thought of why not using gpu accelerated blas library.

Did anyone use to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (2014-05-22)**

AMD has produced a beta release of AMD Core Math Library (ACML) version 6.0 that can offload FFT and BLAS functions to a GPU by using clMath internally.  The announcement is here: [ACML Beta 6.0 Release Leverages the Power of Heterogeneous Compute](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/04/16/acml-beta-6-0-released/).  The caveat here is that input data must be transferred from CPU to GPU and output data returned to the CPU on **each** BLAS or FFT call.  Therefore, AMD has a bunch of scripts for tuning when a problem is large enough that ACML will use the GPU instead of the CPU.

For the sake of completeness, I'll also mention that Nvidia supports similar functionality with its nvBLAS library but that relies on cuBLAS and CUDA so it won't work on anything but Nvidia GPUs.

---

**Original answer**

Unfortunately, AMD's GPU accelerate BLAS library cannot directly link to Numpy or any other application expecting a standard CPU-based BLAS library.  The reason is that existing GPU BLAS libraries all require one to first copy the matrices to the GPU before calling the BLAS functions.  This requires that someone modify Numpy to do this copying.

**Edit:** CLyther looks like it can replace some of what Numpy does and converts everything to OpenCL.  See here: http://srossross.github.io/Clyther/for_numpy_users.html

Answer (score 0):

If memory servers, pyCuda at least, probably also pyOpenCL can work with numPy